# List items being duplicated when moving to new column

Tags: jquery

I pieced together a list where you can move one item from the left column to the right, and vice versa. This also supports an accordion toggle.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qxt0g1s5/1/)

```
$('.list-arrows button').unbind().click(function () {
    var $button = $(this), actives = '';
    if ($button.hasClass('move-left')) {
        actives = $('.list-right ul li.active');
        actives.clone(true, true).removeClass('active').appendTo('.list-left ul');
        actives.remove();
    } else if ($button.hasClass('move-right')) {
        actives = $('.list-left ul li.active');
        actives.clone(true, true).removeClass('active').appendTo('.list-right ul');
        actives.remove();
    }
});
```

When I move Item 1 from Column A to Column B, Item 1 gets cloned and added to Column A's other list items. Not sure why this is happening, but I suspect it has something to do with .appendTo('.list-left ul'); not being specific enough.

So I added an iterative loop to the list items in order to try to keep the clone contained to each specific one, but I think I'm on the wrong track.

Is there a way to be able to move each item into either column but prevent the item itself from being duplicated in every other column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour is due to your selector being too broad when appending the moved item to `<ul>` elements. In your code, these are the two relevant lines:

```
actives.clone(true, true).removeClass('active').appendTo('.list-left ul'); 
// [...]
actives.clone(true, true).removeClass('active').appendTo('.list-right ul');
```

The selectors in `appendTo()` will match *every* `<ul>` that is a child of `.list-right` and `.list-left`, including the `<ul>` elements of the items that already exist in those lists. As such, the moved item will also be added under those items.

To fix this, you could specify that you only want to add the item to the first `<ul>` encountered, as with your current HTML structure that is the correct list. So those two lines become:

```
actives.clone(true, true).removeClass('active').appendTo('.list-left ul:eq(0)');
// and
actives.clone(true, true).removeClass('active').appendTo('.list-right ul:eq(0)');
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qxt0g1s5/3/) with the fix applied.

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.